# Javascript : Opposite of deal.voters.push(user);

Tags: javascript

Im trying to remove a user from an embedded array of users.

I use `deal.voters.push(user);`to add the user to the array but how do i remove the user.

This is the model for the user.

```
var ItemSchema = new Schema({
title: {
    type: String,
    default: 'NA',
    required: 'Please fill Item title',
    trim: true
},
voters: [{
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
}]
```

});

I assumed it would be `deal.voters.pull(user);`but it throws an error.

Comment: There is no remove by a value. You can either remove by pop, shift, or splice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript